# R: Read a matrix into JAGS

Tags: r, matrix, jags

I am trying to read a 10 x 10 matrix into a JAGS model. I called my matrix "matrix1." I have the following and it is not working:

```
for ( i in 1:10) {
    for ( j in 1:10 {
         mat[i,j] <- matrix1 
  }
 }
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are trying to put your matrix "matrix1" into each cell of "mat". What is "mat"? It would help to post how you constructed "matrix1" and "mat".

Comment: thank you, that completely makes sense, I think I've got it from here!